# Select Box with Default Value V-for inside another V-for

Tags: javascript, select, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a list of items and people can add new item.
The item should have an select box and selected value from selectbox should be the item value.

So I tried to bind the select to the item by `v-for key` as below

```
<div id="app">

{{message}}
<span v-on:click="addNewItem">Add New item</span>
<section v-for="(item, key) in items">
{{item.val}}
  <select v-modal="items[key].val">
    <option v-for="default in defaults.selectBox">{{default}}</option>
  </select>
</section>
</div>
```

JS

```
new Vue({
el:'#app',
data: {
message: 'testing',
        defaults:{ selectBox : ['VUE','REACT','ANGULAR']},//some default vaues
    items: [{val:'VUE'},{val: 'REACT'}] //intial two items

   },
  methods:{
  addNewItem:function(){ //add new dynamic items
  this.items.push({val:''});
  }
  }
});
```

But it is not even showing the select box.

What wrong am I doing here. How to achieve this(Selected value should be put on to the item val)?

https://jsfiddle.net/xdx2bbhm/

Comment: How many select boxes do you have here, 3?

Comment: 3 Select box values. But select box can be N based on used add new item @Psidom

Comment: There's a lot of other things going on in your code (`v-modal` for example). I'd recommend creating a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @NateBarbettini `v-modal` is the main thing I'm trying to fix. But may be I don't have expertise in that. I'm trying to bind that to the items val. so that when user select something, then it is added to the item.

Comment: You have one select box, three default values, but can add as many to the `items` array. Is this true?

Comment: Yes. So if a new item added. Then new select box should be shown with default values. When user select the select box then its value should be updated to the current item. @Psidom

Comment: I am still not quite sure. Is this what you intended to have? https://jsfiddle.net/xdx2bbhm/4/

Comment: @Psidom Thanks for the effort, appreciate it. But unfortunately that isn't am looking for. I'm looking to add a select box inside the item itself. So later use can change an item value just by changing the select box near to that item(associated with that item).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a typo mistake.
Instead of `v-modal` it should be `v-model`

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xdx2bbhm/7/)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `default` variable in `option`'s `v-for` by anything else correct the issue

`default` is a JavaScript reserved keyword and VueJS doesn't allow it's use as a property name

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
   message: 'testing',
  defaults: { 
     selectBox : ['VUE','REACT','ANGULAR'] //some default vaues
    },
    items: [{val:'VUE'},{val: 'REACT'}] // intial two items
  },
  methods: {
    addNewItem: function() { // add new dynamic items
     this.items.push({val:'TEST '+this.items.length});
   }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
{{message}}
<span v-on:click="addNewItem">Add New item</span>
<section v-for="(item, key) in items">
{{item.val}}
  <select>
    <option v-for="defaultx in defaults.selectBox">{{ defaultx }}</option>
  </select>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 yes, now the select box are appearing. I want the selected value to be the item value instead of TEST. How do I do it ?

Comment: Which select box have to set the value ? because you have two select boxes at start, what if I select "VUE" and "REACT", what value should the added item have ? Same for 1...N select boxes

Comment: When we add new item, a new select box and item is added. Isn't it? Now I want the item to have the value of what in the new select box.